# $(n-7)(n+7)=$ some perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

This put in the context of a age problem will be:

> the product of my age seven years ago and seven years later is some perfect square

Since this is a age problem that perfect square has to be between 1 and 100. I've try every factor of number between 1 and 100 inclusive, and found none that matches.

Can there be another way besides trial and error?

Comment: This is the same as $n^2 - 7^2 = a^2$, in other words $(n-a)(n+a) = 7^2$.  Can you see how this limits the possibilities?

Comment: Why does the perfect square have to be smaller than $100$?  If my age is $13$, the product of my age seven years ago and my age seven years later is already larger than that.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_factorization_method

Comment: @ErickWong I believe he meant that the age $n$ must between 1 and 100, which would imply that the perfect square must be between 1^2 and 100^2.

Comment: @ErickWong Transforming $(n-7)(n+7)=a^2$ into $(n-a)(n+a)=7^2$ is a beautiful hint.

Comment: I notice that all of the answers so far agree that $n=25$, but are missing $n=7; (7-7)(7+7)=0^2$. Thanks to Erick Wong for a great hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to finding a primitive pythagorean triple, since 7 is a prime number. We are trying to solve $n^2=7^2+m^2$.

We know that any primitive pythagorean triple has one odd leg that is the difference of squares i.e. $7=a^2-b^2$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Such $a$ and $b$ are $a=4$ and $b=3$.

Thus our solution is $n=a^2+b^2=4^2+3^2=25$, and $m=2*a*b=2*4*3=24$, so in turn your age is 25.

Comment: Isn't the second part based on prior knowledge?

Comment: Yes, but you could prove it not too difficultly. If this is supposed to be a solution through very basic means, maybe the answer you are looking for is 7, as (7-7)(7+7)=0*14=0^2.

Comment: @Doeser It is much easier to use Erick's immediate hint, in his first comment to the question. In how many ways can 49 be written as a product of two integers?

Comment: Given that it is easier to solve $(n-m)(n+m)=7^2$, I think the general Pythagorean triple formula is unhelpful. (We also don't know that they are relatively prime.) And it is not nearly as easy to prove as the rest of the problem.

Comment: Coming back to your answer, I still don't get how it works. Your are saying a^2 + b^2 = a^2 - b^2 + 2ab. How did this all happen? I really don't get

Answer (score 0):

$$n = 25$$

$$n^2-49 = k^2$$

$$n^2 = 49 + k^2$$

An easy pythagorean triple containing $7$ is $(7, 24, 25)$

If $n =25$, $k$ could be $24$.

Or $(25-7)(25+7) = 18*32 = 576 = 24^2$

Comment: This is pretty much trial and error

Comment: Solving for an integer solution and the equation can be thought as a representation of a right triangle (as shown previously), this is a Pythagorean triple.  It is not hard to find generating formulas for Pythagorean triples.  Construct a triple with the smaller leg being seven.  Generating triples when one side is known - http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples